# Laravel artisan command ignores php.ini setting for Memcached

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I'm trying to enable memcached on my file server. I have added the line 'memcached.use_sasl = 1' in my php.ini file, and restarted apache2.

A phpinfo(); command shows that memcached.usesasl is set to 1.

However, whenever I run a php artisan command I get the following error message:

> Memcached::setSaslAuthData(): SASL support (memcached.use_sasl) isn't enabled in php.ini

I made sure to run the phpinfo() from within my laravel projects public/index.php to make sure that I was looking at the configuration that Laravel is using (just in case it was using a different php somehow?) and it shows memcached.use_sasl is set to 1.

Comment: Apache-embedded PHP and command-line PHP often use separate ini files. Check for php-cli.ini in the same dir as php.ini. You can also run `php --ini` and it will show what files it uses.

Comment: There is no php-cli.ini file that I can find.

Comment: Alright, php -i shows what file it's using. It is indeed a different file in the /etc/php/7.0/cli directory

Comment: @AlexHowansky if you set that as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache-embedded PHP and command-line PHP often use separate ini files. Check for php-cli.ini in the same dir as php.ini. You can also run `php --ini` and it will show what files it uses.